# extract regular expressions from collapsed characters (including "|")

Tags: r, regex

I want to detect (and then extract) month names from text using `str_detect` and `str_extract`.

For this, I create an object containing all month names and abbreviations.

```
m <- paste(c(month.name, month.abb), collapse = "|")
> m
[1] "January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec"
```

Then, I want to detect any of the entries occurring as a single word (surrounded by word boundaries):

```
stringr::str_detect(c("inJan", "Jan"), str_glue("\\b{m}\\b"))
```

This, however, returns `TRUE TRUE` (I expect `FALSE TRUE`, as the first is not a single word.

I suspect this is due to the collapsing of the list, as `stringr::str_detect(c("inJan", "Jan"), str_glue("\\bJan\\b"))` returns the expected `FALSE TRUE`.

I need to detect occurrences of `m`, however. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Group the alternatives

Comment: `stringr::str_detect(c("inJan", "Jan"), str_glue("\\b({m})\\b"))` does the trick.